# How to solve an error with nodejs filesystem in Cloud Functions for Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

This is the code:

File:`functions\index.js`contains:

```
exports.game=require('firebase-functions').https.onRequest((request,response)=>{
require('fs').readFile('slave.htm',function(err,data){response.send(data.toString())})})
```

And when I deploy the firebase proyect folder, the navigator downloads a binary file `slave` without the extension `.htm`. I want to show `slave.htm` as the response text after client send the request to the `(...).firebaseapp.com` domain, not that the file is downloaded as soon as the page is opened.

Comment: I don't think I understand what the problem is.  Also, could you format your function code so it's easier to read?

Comment: I'm bad at english, remember if this question annoy you I will delete this question.

Comment: In which part do you get lost?